# Remove or Replace last row of a CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, file, csv, overwrite

I am trying to update last line of a csv file, I get the last line with using this code:

```
$f = public_path('MYCSV.csv');
$rows = file($f);
$last_row = array_pop($rows);
$data = str_getcsv($last_row);
```

I searched a lot but did not find any way to replace or at least to remove the last line of csv file, it will be great if do not use foreach loop as the file size is big...

Comment: So what's wrong? You pop out last row from `$rows` put never use it later on.

Comment: Here is your code in working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1adec2f0883b7ff92f719838784c8190b5ab4bb3

Comment: You want to remove the last row and put the $rows again to same CSV File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code: (I don't have Laravel to test on, but I tested with raw php)

```
$f = public_path('MYCSV.csv');
$rows = file($f);
array_pop($rows);                       // remove final element/row from $array
file_put_contents($f, implode($rows));  // convert back to string and overwrite file
```

Now if you want to add a new row to the end of your file, you will just need to push the new data as a comma-separated string (with a trailing newline character) into the `$rows` array.

If you have a .csv file with this content:

```
Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarren House,312,3.75
Belinda Jameson,2017,Cushing House,148,3.52
Jeff Smith,2018,Prescott House,17-D,3.20
Sandy Allen,2019,Oliver House,108,3.48
```

Then `$rows` array, after the `array_pop()` call, will be:

```
array (
  0 => 'Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarren House,312,3.75
',
  1 => 'Belinda Jameson,2017,Cushing House,148,3.52
',
  2 => 'Jeff Smith,2018,Prescott House,17-D,3.20
')
```

*Notice that the newline characters are not lost when `file()` is used -- so no "glue" is necessary with `implode()`.

After `file_put_contents()` is called, the file will be overwritten with:

```
Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarren House,312,3.75
Belinda Jameson,2017,Cushing House,148,3.52
Jeff Smith,2018,Prescott House,17-D,3.20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php try {
    $csv_path = 'MYCSV.csv';
    $fp = fopen($csv_path, 'r+');
    if ($fp) {
        $data = array();
        while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        fclose($fp);


        array_pop($data);
        $fp = fopen($csv_path, 'w+');
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            fputcsv($fp, $value);
        }


    } else {
        throw new Exception("Failed to open file");
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}?>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without adding these two loops?

Comment: I want to replace the last line values, and save it.